# Preview a PDF file in browser with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, preview

I've a question for you.
I would like to display a PDF onto my web browser.

Furthermore, I made this code. It works with Firefox but unfortunately not with Chrome.

```
$content = file_get_contents($path);
var_dump($content);
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$path");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, public");
header("Pragma: public");
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
echo $content;
```

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Doesn't work how, what happens, do you get any errors, etc.?

Comment: Which library you are using for pdf generation in php?

Comment: I've an error on Google Chrome which says PDF loading fail
Here is the preview: [link](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/984074Capture.png)

Comment: Please check chrome setting:

http://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation

Comment: @Raghbendra i'm using the built-in viewer

Comment: @Raghbendra i checked my setting and the viewer is not blocked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must not have a `var_dump()` before the headers (unless you use output buffering without telling us). There must not be any output before sending headers. Also, if you use `var_dump()` to dump the PDF's contents that will introduce surrounding artifacts which probably cause problems with most PDF viewers.

For troubleshooting, please try this minimal working example:

```
<?php
$path = './path/to/file.pdf';

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename='.$path);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

readfile($path);
```

Just as an aside, it is generally also a good idea *not* to use a closing PHP tag (?>) in order to avoid any unwanted accidental whitespace at the end of the file, which could be causing problems; and to stick with one type of quite marks ' or " for your strings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that works perfectly ! :)

Comment: header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename='.$path);
where content-disposition: INLINE did de trick..

Answer (score 1):

I've try it with differents ways..
The best is to make an image with Imagick and display the image..
or 
reduce with Ghostscript ...

Like this, you can make a preview and it's easy with all browsers..
For make PDF->PNG I do like that:

```
$save_to = '.png';
exec('convert -density 300 -trim "'.$file.'" -resize 1000 -quality 85 -colorspace RGB -background white  "'.$destination.$save_to.'" &', $output, $return_var);
```

The & at the end of the destination permit to make differents images for multipage pdf like:
image-1.png
image-2.png 
....

If you want show the PDF, but smaller, you can reduce the PDF, but all browsers don't show the PDF with the same way...

My code for reduce PDF look like that:

```
exec('gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook  -dNOPAUSE  -dBATCH -sOutputFile='.$output_file.' '.$file.' ',$output, $return_var);
```

Comment: what if the pdf has a password, how to open it with its password?